# Php integration with tapkey

Tags: tapkey

Do you have any php exemple integration to grant right for someone for one year on a door?

I have read your GitHub but don't see any information about php exemple.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't have any PHP-specific examples for using rest APIs.

Grant access can be easily done via the rest-based Tapkey Web API:
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_Put

If you want to work with your own external users you have to sign JWT Id Tokens and configure an Identity Provider on https://portal.tapkey.io.
Find more information about this topic here: https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/identity_providers/

To grant access to such users you have then to register this user and create a contact in the owners locking system:
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/identity_providers/

If you want to grant access to a card, the card must be first added to the locking system via the Tapkey App and after creating a grant, the card has to be synchronized via the Tapkey App.
For security reasons, cards are not granted just by allowing the specific uid. Instead, the cars have unique cryptographical keys, which can not be copied.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't find a way to link a card or phone by the API ? My objectif is to create person in my own BDD to after that create access to your TapKey automatically with card or phone. How the link work ?

Comment: It depends how the person in your BDD works. If you want to use the Tapkey app with Tapkey users, create a contact in the locking system https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Contacts/Contacts_Put and the create a grant for this contact https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_Put
For more detailed information please add more information what you try to archive.